# How can I get this value from function stored properly?

Tags: c

```
int num5(int number)
{
    number = 5;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    printf("%d", number);
}
```

I need my main to be able to store number as 5, im just testing it with print number as 5. I realise with this example i could just do

```
return number; //function

int number = num5(number); //main
```

But my program is a bit more complicated and I cant just return number.

Comment: Because it's pass by value.So you have to call `num5(&number);` and receive by `int num5(int* number)`

Comment: "I cant just return number." -- Why not? And given what you have presented here, I would say that you're not yet ready for complicated programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a pointer and de-reference it in the function:

```
int num5(int* pnum)
{
    *pnum = 5;   // you may want to check that pnum is not NULL
    return 0;    // presumably you don't always return 0 in real code
}
```

Then

```
int number = 42;
printf("%d", number); // prints 42
int ret = num5(&number);
printf("%d", number); // prints 5
```

Comment: Please don't persist with the OP's errors ... num5 should return void and its parameter should be called `pnumber`.

Comment: @JimBalter Calling it `pnumber` is just a convention, and not one I would adopt. As for the return value, OP claims this is a simplification of a larger problem. I modified the code to use the return value.

Comment: Sure, you could call it numberp, or ptrToNumber, or whatever, but it's not a number and no one calling it that would pass a code review or interview with me. I'm not talking about Hungarian here, which I am no fan of, just semantically accurate names. I do appreciate the other changes you made, though.

Comment: @JimBalter Fair enough, `number` is not suitable in this case. But the type of the parameter should be enough. Nobody writing code where you can't clearly see what the type of a name from the context (if the type actually matters) would pass a job interview with me.

Comment: Fortunately for you you're not at the beginning of your career, or you would have a rough time in the future (which is already here) with type inference. Sizable Haskell programs have been written with no types mentioned ... all statically typed and completely type safe. The real problem here is that the thing is called "number" rather than what it represents, but that's fair for a mere example and I'll admit to excessive pedantry ... sorry about that.

Comment: @JimBalter I was referring only to C. Different languages (or different parts of, say, C++) have different requirements. I wouldn't apply the same rules to, say, python, or generic programming in C++ (where you may not care about the type, but about characteristics of the type.)

Comment: Python has dynamic typing, and C++ template programming is close to duck typing. There is nothing at all C-specific about "Nobody writing code where you can't clearly see what the type of a name from the context (if the type actually matters) would pass a job interview with me". You're backpedaling and nothing you say will convince me otherwise ... I won't comment further.

Comment: @JimBalter It is C specific because I was talking about this particular example.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Pass by value method. What ever the changes takes places in the function it won't affect in the main program. Those changes are limited with in the function.

You need use the following method to do this!

```
int num5(int *number)
{
    *number = 5;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    number = num5(&number); // pass the address of the number instead value
    printf("%d", number);
}
```

When you Pass the address of the variable to the function, whatever the changes you are doing in the function, that is retained by that variable. So you will get the latest assigned value!

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, call by reference [a.k.a. call by address] will do the job for you. To be on safer side, don't forget to add a `NULL` pointer check to your incoming pointer. Also, as per usual convention, `main()` should return 0 in case of successful completion of execution.

#### Modified Code:

```
int num5(int *number)
{
   if (number)                       //NULL check for incoming pointer
   {
       *number = 5;
   }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    number = num5(&number); // pass the address of the number instead value
    printf("%d", number);

    return 0;               //for convention
}
```